# Allow anonymous access to a special file in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, css, forms-authentication, dotless

I started using dotless in my asp.net site which requires a special httphandler to work. The site uses Forms Authentication. Here's the problem: When I'm logged in the request to http://example.org/stylesheets/mystyles.less works fine. It gives me back the appropriate css. If I'm not logged in the request is denied and I'm redirected to the login page. Is there a way to allow this file to be accessed anonymously? This is not working:

```
<location path="~/stylesheets">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Is this happening in IIS (which version?) or in your local ASP.Net development server?

Comment: Can you access a standard .css file in ~/stylesheets (when not logged in) ? ie is your authorization node correct?

Comment: IIS7. Whether I add deny="*" or allow="*" it has no affect on my ability to access .css or .less files.

Comment: This will only affect files that get processed through the ASP.Net engine so it will not affect .css or .less files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is with the path syntax.

This does not work:

```
<location path="~/stylesheets">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

This DOES work:

```
<location path="stylesheets">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem but you're missing a quote mark in your xml.

```
<location path="~/stylesheets">
```