# CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net

I am running website on my localhost (Windows 7). I am getting "CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch".
Javascript and images are also not loading.

I have enabled anonymous authentication on my local IIS.
Static Content feature is installed on my local IIS.

My web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Login.aspx" timeout="30" path="/" protection="All" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users ="?" />
  <allow users = "*" />
</authorization>
```

Still CSS, Javascript and images not loading. 
Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow all users to access static assets. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1923328/254973 to see some examples of what you need to add to the web.config.

Comment: This works when I start website directly from Visual Studio (press F5), url is like this: http://localhost:52240/Default.aspx But when I enter to browser http://localhost/Login.aspx it still does not work :(

Comment: I don't understand your issue. The static assets load when you visit the default page locally, but on the login page they don't work?

Comment: No. Static assets load, when I run website directly from visual studio (you know when you press F5 in VS, solution compiles and website loads in the browser). In this case it works fine. But when I start same website on my local IIS (Control Panel->Administrative Tools -> IIS Manager ->New Website), CSS is still not loading...

Comment: P.S. That is happening when I access Login.aspx. But when I am logged in, CSS loads fine.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Was using wrong config file. Your advice was very helpful, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `allow=*` does not include unauthenticated users in newer version of IIS configuration. For unauthenticated users to access your files you must also have `allow=?` in your web.config.

Your `deny=?` is the problem with you not being able to load the images or stylesheets when not logged in.